# Show me how the sky is like in Jupiter (but not mars)

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy, moon, jupiter

Assuming someone is "standing" on the "surface" of Jupiter (ok, in a stable position deep inside the gas giant's gravity field analog to standing on the surface of a rock planet) where the moons can be seen during the night, how would be the sky like during a lunar "month" cycle of all the moons around the planet (a lunar month defined as the interval of time it takes for all the moons to show the same configuration again)?

Do all the moons chase one another at a fixed distance, or do they cross and bypass one another like a race?

How long is a lunar month in Jupiter?

Comment: If the question can be improved, please say it in a comment (or edit it).

Comment: See also: [NASA/JPL Solar System Simulator](https://space.jpl.nasa.gov/)

Comment: @Loong this simulator cannot show the view from the planet's surface.

Comment: How stable is this stable position you're talking about? If you're deep enough into Jupiter that it can support your weight, I doubt you'd be able to see much beyond the atmosphere. BTW, this question may be more appropriate for the Astronomy site.

Comment: @PM2Ring we handwave the fact that one cannot "stand" on a gas giant. Observer might be over a very large flotation device. A question might fit several different stacks, but the specialists are not the same (even though there are several in common). Cross posting is also bad. If I don't get answers here, I will close this question and post there, but I want a more analytical answer, therefore physics.se

Comment: @PM2Ring "where the moons can still be seen in the sky"

Comment: Free package Celestia can render this and more. https://celestia.space/    tough Jupiter can be among the trickiest things to simulate. ...

Comment: @Alchimista can it render views from the "surface"? - (*I know it doesn't apply to gas giants*)

Comment: Yes. It is amazing your are not confined to earth! Really quality

Comment: @Alchimista thanks. I'll try once I get to my PC. And it is FOSS!!